# Double NAT MTU setting for the inner network

Tags: router, nat, tcpip, mtu

I have a home network with two routers, one behind another. The outer router's WAN port is a VDSL2 PPPoE connection with a live IP address and the MTU size of 1492. The inner router's WAN port is assigned via DHCP as just another client on the outer router's LAN network. The default MTU for it was 1500 by default. I've changed it to 1492 to match the outer router.

Now I wonder if it makes any sense to further reduce the MTU size for the inner network. Would that make the inner network more robust in this double NAT scenario?

Comment: Do you have a reason to double NAT? It's usually much easier to bridge the network and extend it.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart, the reason is mostly to keep my work-related PCs/VMs/devices behind a separate firewall from the rest of my home network users/devices, but still being able to see and access those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NAT just changes IP addresses/ports in the packets, it does not include any extra information (headers etc.) in the packet. Therefore it doesn't reduce the MTU in any way, and having the same MTU is fine.

Comment: Should I still be setting the WAN MTU on the *inner* router to 1492? Or leave it at 1500?

Comment: MTU discovery can be tricky, and I am no expert on all cases that can go wrong, or that will work even with different MTUs. If you experience bad performance on outgoing packets, first thing to try is definitely to set MTU on the inner router to 1492, to avoid fragmenting outgoing packets. And it doesn't hurt to do this right from the start. In doubt, measure with tcpdump etc. to see if something *does* get fragmented.

Answer (score 1):

While NAT doesn't increase the size of packets (or, perhaps more accurately, decrease the maximum payload size per packet), PPoE and other tunnelling protocols often do.

However, most modern operating systems have implemented [Path MTU Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery), outlined in [RFC1191](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1191), which, optimally, will adapt outgoing packets to that of the smallest MTU of any of the links between the sending host and the destination, automatically.  It does this by setting the `DF bit` (Don't Fragment) in large outbound packets, and looks for an ICMP error `Fragmentation Needed`.

In MacOS, and other Unix-like operating systems, the `ping` utility has multiple switches that can set the `DF bit`, and set the payload size, and even sweep a range of sizes, effectively determining an MTU between the source host and destination.  There are 8 bytes of overhead in the `ICMP Echo Request` `ping` sends out, and 20 bytes overhead in the IP packet, making the maximum payload of 1472 for a ping packet with the `DF bit` set on an 1500 byte MTU  interface.

You could set your MTU lower to optimize, in some very small way, this one particular path, in return for a very slightly less optimal packet size for *every other* packet stream that host participates in.

So, unless you're having problems with file transfers stalling, it might be best to let the operating system handle MTU automatically.

```
[nevin-mac-mini:~] nevin% ping -c 1 -D -s 1472 192.168.2.1
PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1): 1472 data bytes
1480 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.667 ms

--- 192.168.2.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.667/0.667/0.667/0.000 ms
[nevin-mac-mini:~] nevin% ping -c 1 -D -s 1473 192.168.2.1
PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1): 1473 data bytes
ping: sendto: Message too long

--- 192.168.2.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm aware of PMTUD and even implemented MSS Clamping on my router ([here's a follow up](https://www.snbforums.com/threads/set-mtu-for-clients-in-lan-wifi-wlan.42483/#post-399938) on this) but I still have occasional issues with HTTPS sites in Chrome/Win10. I'm going to manually configure MTU manually via netsh and see if it changes anything.

Comment: I don't have access to any windows boxes to look at their latest implementation of `ping`, but the MacOS/BSD version allows size sweeping with the -g/-G flags, so `ping -D -g 1450 -G 1500 host.name` would help.

Do your issues involve sending data (such as uploading images), or receiving it?  If the latter, then the possible MTU issue is on the remote side, and almost out of your control:  Ensure your devices can and do send ICMP error messages when large packets are received.